# problem printing a string within except? Program just ends instead of printing statement

Tags: python, windows

The program isn't printing what I want ("too slow") after the except with the KeyboardInterrupt, which should end the program and print the string, instead the program just ends. I tried messing around with it a bit but can't seem to figure it out. What should I do?

```
import os
import signal
import threading
from random import randint

def timed_input(interval, *args):
    t = threading.Timer(interval, os.kill, args=(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT))    
    t.start()
    try:
        return int(input(*args))
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        t.cancel()

while True:
    want = randint(1,9)
    try:
        got = timed_input(5, f'type "{want}": ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('too slow')
    else:
        if got != want:
            print('You Lose.')
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your first function is removing the `KeyboardInterrupt` thus making the second try block useless.

To fix this add another except block for the first function so it is properly raised:

```
import os
import signal
import threading
from random import randint

def timed_input(interval, *args):
    t = threading.Timer(interval, os.kill, args=(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT))    
    t.start()
    try:
        return int(input(*args))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
    except ValueError:
        pass
    finally:
        t.cancel()

while True:
    want = randint(1,9)
    try:
        got = timed_input(5, f'type "{want}": ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('too slow')
    else:
        if got != want:
            print('You Lose.')
            break
```

Comment: To reraise the exception all you need is `raise` — or leave the `except` out altogether.

Comment: @martineau thanks! I figured they would want the other except block to handle other exceptions.

Comment: Generally speaking it's usually a bad idea to to a have "bare" `except:` block like that, especially one followed by `pass`.

Comment: What I suspect they actually want is for `timed_input` to only catch `ValueError` (so that it ignores non-numeric input).

Comment: I tried to add an except block to the function but the code still runs the same way: If no input is given it only ends the loop but doesn't display the "You lose" string. The reason i did it using except block is because it was the only intuitive solution for me, since I'm trying to make the user "lose the game" if no input is given in a certain time so the program checks the funciton for an input (I'm relatively new at python).

Comment: So I'm still not sure how to get it working how i'd like. In other scenarios (for example the user types the wrong integer or doesn't type an integer at all, the program works as intended. It's just the issue with the time_input() scenario.

Comment: @hzm the answer here should work to capture the keyboard interrupt as you ask. If you want the `too slow` message to appear after a certain time (this os a different question) you can use the time functions to create a timer and check e.g every few milliseconds if the condition is met.

Comment: fixed! seems like the problem was a misunderstanding on my part of the keyboardinterrupt exception